How to prevent small-protein smearing in SDS-PAGE?
I am doing SDS-PAGE for ubiquitin-6xhis (9.6kDa), and all my hand-cast gels produce a smeared band (see image). I typically use 5% acrylamide for stacking, 15% for resolving gel layers. I don't understand the biophysics of PAGE enough to know what changes to make to mitigate this smearing, any ideas?

